# Use matrix values as indices

Tags: r, combinatorics

I'm doing Fisher's permutation test, in which I have to generate all combinations of treatment status.

We have 4 subjects, 2 of which are treated. Using `combn`, I can generate all combinations of treated subjects. For example, the first row means that the first and second subjects are treated.

```
t(combn(4, 2))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

How do I go from this matrix to a matrix of treatment status as follows:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0   0
[2,]    1    0    1   0
...
```

Comment: This could be done using the `FUN` option in `combn` `+(t(combn(4,2, FUN=function(x) 1:4 %in% x)))`

Comment: @akrun's comment actually works best (i.e. simplest to understand). (Could you post it as an answer?) heroka's answer probably has a minor typo, since I'm getting error. MichaelChirico's answer is fastest.

Comment: I benchmarked vs. @akrun's & his is lightyears faster (3000x faster for 20 choose 10).

Comment: @MichaelChirico   Are you saying that using `FUN` outside `combn` is faster?

Comment: @akrun no, just the opposite. your snippet above (`combn(m,n,FUN=...)`) ran much much faster than the answer I posted for large `m`,`n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my comment as a solution.  It is a modification of @Heroka's suggestion.  The `+` will convert the `logical` to `numeric` and should be faster than `as.integer`.

```
+(t(combn(4,2, FUN=function(x) 1:4 %in% x)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    1    1    0
#[5,]    0    1    0    1
#[6,]    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 6):

Using base-R:

```
res <- t(apply(t(combn(4,2)),MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){
  return(as.numeric(1:4 %in% x))
}))
> res
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: Following @akrun's suggestion of  `FUN` in `combn` and inspiration from your `1:4 %in% x`, I think that this is the simplest answer: `t(combn(4, 2, FUN = function(x) { return(as.numeric(1:4 %in% x)) }))`

Comment: using `as.integer` should be even faster.

Answer (score 5):

How about just:

```
out <- matrix(0L, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = max(x))

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) out[i, x[i, ]] <- 1L

> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1
```

We can also do this without a loop, though it may be a little less readable (thanks @Frank for the footwork):

```
m <- matrix(0L, choose(4, 2), 4)
m[cbind(rep(1:choose(4, 2), each = 2), c(combn(4, 2)))] <- 1L
```

Easily wrapped into a function:

```
participants <- function(m, n){
  if (n > m) stop( )
  mcn <- choose(m, n)
  out <- matrix(0L, mcn, m)
  out[cbind(rep(1:mcn, each = n), c(combn(m, n)))] <- 1L
  out
}

> participants(6, 5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    0    1    1    1
[5,]    1    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: You can use (1) `choose` to get the number of combos and (2) matrix assignment instead of looping: `m <- matrix(0L,choose(4,2), 4); m[cbind(rep(1:choose(4,2),each=2), c(combn(4,2)))] <- 1L`. Same idea.